# DataGridCheckboxColumn to DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

Within a DataGrid I would like to change the color of the rows according to certain conditions on the ViewModel.

While this seems to be an easy task in WPF, in silverlight you can't have Bindings to properties within Style definitions, you won't be able to utilize the RowBackground of the datagrid either.

Instead I had to change each columnheader, from DataGridTextColumn to DataGridTemplateColumn and create my own textbox in there wrapped by a Grid.  There i would bind the Background of Grid to the conditional color choice within my ViewModel.

This all works fine.  However I experience a problem when I try to replicate DataGridCheckboxColumn into a DataGridTemplateColumn.  Also here I create a Checkbox within a grid and can set the color accordingly, hoever the checkbox can even be ticked on and off, even if the datagrid is set to Readonly.  The checkbox within doesn't seem to care about the readonly state of the datagrid.

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
       <CheckBox.IsChecked>
          <Binding Path=Sales Mode="TwoWays"/>
       <CheckBox.IsChecked>
    </CheckBox> 
  </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Does anyone know why and if there is a more efficient way of doing what i am trying to achieve in Silverlight?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Please check also this post for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464445/odd-behaviour-when-replacing-datagridcheckboxcolumn-with-a-datagridtemplatecolumn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be specifying a `CellTemplate` and a `CellEditingTemplate` for a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Something like the following should work:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      IsChecked="{Binding SomeProperty}">
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      IsChecked="{Binding SomeProperty}"
                      IsEnabled="False">
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[This](http://blogs.profitbase.com/tsenn/?p=53) workaround for bindings within a style may be of interest also.

Comment: Simon, you are hardcoding the IsReadOnly for the particular column. It should bind by default to the datagrid's state.  e.g. with a TextBox it works fine, I dont know yet whats so special about CheckBox yet. And yes I have also the EditingTemplate implemented. Thank you

Comment: @Kave take the `IsReadOnly` off the template column and you will see that the column will respect the value from `DataGrid.IsReadOnly` (so in essence the solution works). The key part to it working is the `IsEnabled="false"` on the `CheckBox` from the `CellTemplate`, notice it is not set in the `CellEditingTemplate` so takes the default value of true for edit mode.