# Odd behaviour when replacing DataGridCheckBoxColumn with a DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have discovered an odd behaviour when replacing a DataGridCheckBoxColumn against a DataGridTemplateColumn that contains a Checkbox.

```
 <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsInReadOnlyMode}">                                        
   <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
     <sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Sales" Binding="{Binding Path=Sales}" />
   </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
 </sdk:DataGrid>
```

When the DataGrid is readonly then the checkbox is also disabled. The code above works correct.

Now if I want to achieve the same thing by using DataGridTemplateColumn, the checkbox doesn't seem to disable itself when the DataGrid is in ReadOnly mode.

```
<sdk:DataGrid Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsInReadOnlyMode}">                                        
   <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
     <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sales" >
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <CheckBox>
                                            <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                                <Binding Path="Sales" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                                            </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <CheckBox>
                                            <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                                <Binding Path="Sales" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                                            </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
 </sdk:DataGrid>
```

One other thing I noticed that might help to explain this is that the checkbox inside DataGridCheckBoxColumn is always disabled until you actually doubleclick the containing cell. Only then once in edit mode I can access the Checkbox.

In the CheckBox I created myself inside DataGridTemplateColumn, the checkbox seem always to be active and can be ticked on and off without even doubleclicking the cell first.

Btw I am using it in Silverlight4, but I am pretty sure it must be the same in WPF.

Can somebody explain to me why that is please?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the double click in case of `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` and no click in case of  `DataGridTemplateColumn`, I think this is happening because inside the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` the `CellTemplate` and  `EditingCellTemplate` would have been implemented differently. In case of `CellTemplate` it would be defined as `readonly` and once you double click you go in editing mode i.e. `EditingCellTemplate` and only then you can modify the `checkbox` and it makes sense.

Now in your case as you have defined both the editing and non-editing template same, so the checkbox is always ready to accept the input

Regarding your main question that why the `checkbox` in `custom template` mode is not following the `GridReadOnly` option, I think this is happening due to the fact that once you define `cell templates` yourself i.e. `cellEditing` template and `non-editing celltemplate` it becomes your responsibility to handle the read only behavior of cells. The option applied on the grid such as read only won't have any effect in templatedcolumn case